# Rails - Verify domain for set custom messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cross-domain, haml

so im studying ROR using rails 4 and im trying to verify the current domain in my app, and set custom messages for each domain.

I have something like this in my app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    //verify the domain here
    //store in a var?
    %meta{ content: 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'http-equiv' => 'Content-Type' }
    %meta{ content: 'Set the message according each domain here', name: 'description'}
```

Someone may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the domain from the request object, which is available in views/controllers/helpers:

```
request.domain
```

Better practice us to set the messages in the controller action, and then just display them in the view, e.g.:

```
def my_action
  @domain_message = get_domain_message(request.domain)
end

def get_domain_message(domain)
  case domain
  when 'example.com' then 'domain specific message'
  when 'egzample.com' then 'another domain specific message'
  end
end
```

Now `@domain_message` is available for use in the view.

Comment: thaks!!! i'm trying now to call method in my view views/folder/index.html.haml using this line:


`= @get_domain_message 'domain'`


but this don't works and have no display error messages

Comment: @wtkd, in the example I set the instance variable `@domain_message`, so `@get_domain_message` would not work. The instance variable needs to be set elsewhere, like the controller.

Comment: ok! it works for me using #{ get_domain_message } thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a hash like this:

```
messages = {"www.example.com" => "Message for www.example.com", "www.example2.com" => "Message for www.example2.com"}
```

now you can display message using this:

```
messages[request.host]
```